# Debug stored procedure in Oracle

Tags: java, database, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which is called from a Java application. I need to debug that stored procedure in order to understand the flow.

Is there a way or good tool with which I can debug stored procedures after the Java application calls it?

Currently, I am using TOra as the database client with Oracle database.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: From Java you can not debug a stored procedure in Oracle. However, you may get some return values from stored procedure at different points which you can check in your java code.

Comment: Did you try Oracle's SQL Developer: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html

Comment: Use Toad For Oracle (http://www.quest.com/toad-for-oracle/) to debug from Toad.  Not sure how to debug if Java is calling the proc.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Means you have to generate a debug file and then parse it in the program. Right?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think you mean http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_debug.htm :)

Comment: @VincentMalgrat: sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [remote debugging with SQL Developer](http://sueharper.blogspot.com/2006/07/remote-debugging-with-sql-developer_13.html).

There are many tools for debugging Oracle PL/SQL but almost all of them use the limited DBMS_DEBUG.  As far as I know only SQL Developer allows you to use the more powerful DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.